# Hide default Wordpress 'home' page from the navigation

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to hide the default Wordpress home page from my website navigation

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/portraits

I am using Twenty Eleven as the parent theme but I was wondering whether it was possible to do this using CSS rather than editing the header.php which doesn't seem to work when I remove any reference to 'home'

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />



<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
                <div class="site-title"><a href="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/home-2"><img src="http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/wp-content/themes/child/images/photosdirector.png"></a></div>

            <?php
                // Check to see if the header image has been removed
                $header_image = get_header_image();
                if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    // The header image
                    // Check if this is a post or page, if it has a thumbnail, and if it's a big one
                    if ( is_singular() &&
                            has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
                            ( /* $src, $width, $height */ $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array( HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) ) ) &&
                            $image[1] >= HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) :
                        // Houston, we have a new header image!
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' );
                    else : ?>
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>" height="<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?>

            <?php
                // Has the text been hidden?
                if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :
            ?>
                <div class="only-search<?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php
                else :
            ?>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
    </header><!-- #branding -->


    <div id="main">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header.php is loading the menu dynamically from the Wordpress dashboard. Edit the menu here: Dashboard > Appearance > Menus